# Getting Constraints Object in SimpleWebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, constraints, webrtc, getusermedia

I am doing a **simpleWebRTC** `demo` to create a livestream session.

What I want to achieve is this:

1. Person is the leader. The leader can broadcast his audio and video.
2. The rest who join are followers. They can only see and hear the leader's broadcast.

To do this in regular **webRTC**, we have the constraints object, wherein we can say:

```
{audio: false, video: false}
```

However, in **simpleWebRTC** `object`, I do not see a constraints `object` exposed.

How to accomplish this using **simpleWebRTC**?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this document here says (https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html):

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
  localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
  remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
  autoRequestMedia: true,
  url: 'https://example.com/'
  //use the media options to pass constraints for getUserMedia requests
  media: mediaOptions
});
```

Or you have to modify the library:

```
SimpleWebRTC.prototype.startLocalVideo = ->
  self = this
  this.config.constraints ||= {video: true, audio: true}
  this.webrtc.startLocalMedia this.config.constraints, (err, stream)->
    if err
      self.emit(err)
    else
      attachMediaStream(stream,
        self.getLocalVideoContainer(),
        {muted: true, mirror: true})
```

then

```
webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC
  localVideoEl: 'localVideo'
  remoteVideosEl: 'remotes'
  autoRequestMedia: true
  debug: true
  detectSpeakingEvents: true
  autoAdjustMic: false
  constraints:
    audio: true
    video:
      mandatory:
        maxWidth: 320
        maxHeight: 180
```

here's the hack
http://blog.dev.zyncro-china.com/2014/02/25/hacking-simplewebrtc-js-to-change-the-video-resolution/